# Calling a Key:Value pair in Google Apps Script is returning "Undefined" instead of the value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, finance

```
var api_key_id = '1234567890'
function open(ticker, date) {
  ticker="TSLA";
  date="2019-01-14";
  var url = "https://api.polygon.io/v1/open-close/" + ticker + "/" + date + "?apiKey=" + api_key_id;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

When the above code is ran it logs this:

> {"status":"OK","from":"2019-01-14T03:30:00Z","symbol":"TSLA","open":342,"high":343.3,"low":335.37,"close":338.93,"afterHours":336.2148,"volume":4425458}

But when I try to do this:

```
Logger.log(data.open);
```

The output is:

> undefined

Is the "data" variable not actually an object? What am I missing?

**EDIT: Solution Found:**
Parsing the result of getContentText() as JSON allowed the desired variable to be called, see below. Thanks to chuckx for pointing this out!

```
var api_key_id = '1234567890'
function open(ticker, date) {
  var url = "https://api.polygon.io/v1/open-close/" + ticker + "/" + date + "?apiKey=" + api_key_id;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = response.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(data);
  Logger.log(json.open);
```

Comment: The request is asynchronous and the code was already executed by the time the response was returned due to which you are seeing it as `undefined`.

Comment: The [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch) is not an asynchronous API. The issue here is that [HTTPResponse.getContextText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response.html#getContentText()) returns a string, so it is in fact not an object.

Comment: chuckx if I try to log just the variable `response` from URLFetchApp it prints the exact same thing as logging the variable `data` after running getContextText().  I think you're right that it converts `response` into a string but I still get `undefined` when I call `response.open` meaning that the UrlFetchApp is also not returning an object or it is acting asynchronously.

Comment: I did a type check on `response` and it is in fact returning an object after URLFetchApp. But `Logger.log(response.open)` is still `undefined`.

Comment: `response` is an instance of the [`HTTPResponse` class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response.html). Accessing the response content as properties of that class doesn't make sense. Alternatively, you can parse the JSON that the API returns, using something like `var api_response= JSON.parse(response.getContentText())`.

Comment: Parsing the JSON allowed me to call the value I wanted! Thanks, this is solved.

Comment: Could you post the solution, so others can see how you solved the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, I edited my post with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`HTTPResponse.getContextText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response.html#getContentText()) returns a string, so it is in fact not an object.

Since this API returns JSON, you can parse the string using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and then interact with the returned object in the manner you're expecting.

```
...
var apiResponse= JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
Logger.log(apiResponse.open);
```